# Failing tests when using PHPUnit with code coverage and Travis CI

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, code-coverage, travis-ci

I am using PHPUnit to run tests in my Symfony2 project and Travis CI. Everything is fine when I am using it without generating code coverage - all tests are pasing. When code coverage option is enabled several tests are failing.

What is the difference between running environment with and without code coverage which might affect tests correctness?

Comment: There should be no difference, but based on you giving no more information than "it does not work", it is hard to tell. Give us some code, the exact output from PHPUnit, and probably try to prepare a test case where only one test runs and fails with/without code coverage.

Comment: Could you please link to failing build? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check error logs to see what is happening. But as I remember when you enable coverage reporting `xdebug` comes in. 
Xdebug has it's maximum nesting level of `100`. This could be the case.

Comment: Thx for the tip, but unfortunately it is not a problem because failures are directly from assertions.

Comment: Please provide exact assertion with exact output :)